# logarithm of a sum or addition

Tags: summation, logarithms

I search a general rule for calculating the logarithm of a sum or addition.
I know that $$\ln{(a+b)}=\ln{\left(a\left(1+\frac b a\right)\right)}=\ln{(a)}+\ln{\left(1+\frac b a\right)}$$
but when the sum implies more terms, how to generalize its calculation/computation? For example when $$\ln{(a+b+c)}$$ or when $$\ln{\left(\sum_i{a_i}\right)}$$ like when we have to compute the denominator of a Bayes formula using log-likelihoods?
Thanks for your incoming help.

Comment: There is no such rule as you mean it

Comment: Well you can say that $ln(a+b+c) = ln(a*(1+(b+c)/a)) = ln(a) + ln(1+(b+c)/a)$.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for looking for such rule? If it is for computing I wouldn't say there's a particular benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same thing you can do with more than three terms $$\ln { (a+b+c) } =\ln { \left( \left( a+b \right) \left( 1+\frac { c }{ a+b }  \right)  \right)  } =\ln { \left( a+b \right) +\ln { \left( 1+\frac { c }{ a+b }  \right)  }  } =$$ $$ =\ln { \left( a\left( 1+\frac { b }{ a }  \right)  \right) +\ln { \left( 1+\frac { c }{ a+b }  \right)  }  } =\ln { a+\ln { \left( 1+\frac { b }{ a }  \right)  } +\ln { \left( 1+\frac { c }{ a+b }  \right)  }  } $$